# Should we have a canonical "Plexus Network" (polygon lines and dots) question & answer pair?

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

I've seen a number of repeated questions around the general Plexus Network topic, mostly of the "what is this called and how to make it?" variety, some specific to motion graphics like After Effects, some aimed more at Illustrator / Affinity Designer style vector illustrations - we've a fair few very good answers out there (especially some created today) with a number of excellent resource links etc - seems to me that it's coming up often enough to consider a canonical on this one.

See:

[Fastest way to create a 'network of connected dots' graphic?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/127665/fastest-way-to-create-a-network-of-connected-dots-graphic)

[What this networking grid style effect called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/98949/what-this-networking-grid-style-effect-called)

[What is this «minimalistic dots» video style called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110858/what-is-this-minimalistic-dots-video-style-called/110880#110880)

[What are these line and dot graphs called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55290/what-are-these-line-and-dot-graphs-called)

What are people's thought on aggregating all this disparate data into one simple-to-maintain location?

Comment: probably yes...

Comment: Knock yourself out ^_^

Comment: I'm erring between "Knock yourself out" and my strong wish to see plexuses go away for a long time :) Might be good to add a part about overuse and trying to make them more interesting...

Comment: Why is it  called a plexus network? I mean every tool capable of darwing  networks can do this.

Comment: @joojaa - I agree with you - but my response when folks wanted a name for it that it's most commonly called that in the 3D generailist and 3D mo-graphics communities, cos that's the case. Used with that nomenclature in 3DS Max, and After Effects, where there's a plug-in literally named Plexus. For myself, when I've created something similar at customer request, I've done it in modo with the procedural geometry tools there and no plug-ins, so until I encountered it being used in AE & 3DS and heard it being referred to as "a Plexus" I thought of it as "triangulated network of nodes" myself.